# Editable JCombobox avoid multiple DocumentEvents when the selection change from the popup

Tags: java, swing, events, listener, jcombobox

I have an editable JComboBox with a single listener on it.

It is a documentListener that execute some code when the user insert or remove some text inside the combobox textfield:

```
 ((JTextComponent)combobox.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).getDocument().addDocumentListener(..)
```

My problem is that when the user select an element from the popup and the content of the combobox textfield changes there are two events executed into the documentListener, one is a removeUpdate() corresponding to the deletion of the previous content and the other is a insertUpdate() corresponding to the insertion of the new value. 
I want that only one execution of my code is done and not two. How can I avoid that the code is executed two times when the user select an entry from the popup?

I tried various combination of different listener but for now without result.

What I want in the end is that my code is execute only one time when:
 - The user change the text into the combobox textfield.
 - The user select an element from the combobox popup

Thanks in advance.

[EDIT 1]
As requested I updated adding SSCCE

```
myCombobox = new javax.swing.JComboBox<String>();
myCombobox.setEditable(true);
((JTextComponent)myCombobox.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).getDocument().addDocumentListener(
    new DocumentListener(){
    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        System.out.println("insert performed");
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        System.out.println("remove performed");
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        System.out.println("change performed");
    }
});

myCombobox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() { 
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
       if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
          System.out.println("Action performed");
       }
  }
});
```

Note that in this case I have an ItemEvent instead of an ActionEvent because I'm continuing to modify my code searching for a solution in any case the behavior should not be influenced by this.

Comment: `As requested I updated adding SSCCE` - that code is not a SSCCE. We can't compile or execute the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can check `((JTextComponent)combobox.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).hasFocus()` to be sure user types in the editor.

Comment: Yes but in this manner i can not catch the events relative to a selection change made via the popup.

Comment: Why can't you catch? Also you can try to listing editing start setting some flag and reset it back after editing end/cancel.

Comment: Unfortunately the editorComponent continue to have the focus also when I select an entry from the pop-up. 
Furthermore I can not use a variable because the DocumentEvent seems to be triggered before that the actionEvent when the selection changes.

Comment: Update your question with SSCCE

Comment: @user2572526, `I can not use a variable because the DocumentEvent seems to be triggered before that the actionEvent when the selection changes` - wrap the DocumentEvent code in a SwingUtilities.invoke(...) so the code is placed at the end of the EDT which means it will execute after the ActionEvent.